# Use optional arguments in SQLCLR

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

I have a stored procedure in MSSQL 2005 Server SQLCLR.
Is it possible to define an optional argument to it?
If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest, if not tidiest, solution that comes to mind is to use a 'shim' stored procedure with default values for optional parameters that calls the inner stored procedure with these default values, much as you use method overloading for 'optional' parameters in C# 3 and earlier.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm doing for now, but I'm trying to avoid having multiple store procedures for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Is there something wrong with just passing in Nulls for the values you want defaulted?
Granted this may not work in every situation.
Sometimes you may want to know if the actual value is indeed Null, and therefore avoid using the default.
If this is the case, then  I would resort to adding an additional "*Default*" parameter.

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void MySproc(SqlInt32 pID, SqlBoolean UseDefault_pID)
{
    pID = (UseDefault_pID == SqlBoolean.True && pID == SqlInt32.Null)
        ? SomeDefaultPIDValue : pID;
}
```

This saves on having to write additional "*wrapper*" sprocs to take in optional parameters with default values that then call your CLR sproc.

To use the Default-Value when Null pass in: UseDefault_pID = 1
To keep the Actual-Value when Null pass in: UseDefault_pID = 0

Comment: Nothing wrong I guess. Seeing as this was 3.5 years ago, I don't remember the original case. I can only guess that it was a procedure with several optional parameters, so the default checking code might get long.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass it as null, and then do something like this:

```
create proc sp_find_person
 @fname varchar(30)
 @lname varchar(60)
as
begin
 select * from person a
 where (a.fname = @fname or @fname is null) 
   and (a.lname = @lname or @lname is null);
end
go
```

Passing both parameters as null would return all rows from person.

Passing @fname with a value and @lname null would return all persons with that @fname.

Passing @lname with a value and @fname null would return all persons with that @lname.

Passing both with a non-null value would find all persons with that the specified fname and lname.